# Does not contain a constructor that takes x arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, webforms

Using visual studio this error occurred randomly. I tried to clean the build with no success. The class can see every other constructor for the classes that are contained in that folder but the dates. For example the it can see the connection constructor

[image: Visual Studio]

```
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (!(rdr == null || !rdr.HasRows))
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {

        Dates dates = new Dates(rdr.GetGuid(0), rdr.GetString(1), 
            rdr.GetDateTime(2), rdr.GetString(3), rdr.GetString(4), 
            rdr.GetDateTime(5));
        yield return dates;

    }

}
```

Dates Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace GoDating.Models
{
    public class Dates
    {
        public Guid id;
        public string firstname;
        public DateTime dob;
        public string Image;
        public string dateLocation;
        public DateTime date;


        public Dates(Guid id, string firstname, DateTime dob, string Image,string dateLocation,DateTime date)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.firstname = firstname;
            this.dob = dob;
            this.Image = Image;
            this.dateLocation = dateLocation;
            this.date = date;
        }

    }
}
```

Connection class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace GoDating.Models
{
    public class Connection
    {
        public Guid id;
        public string firstname;
        public DateTime dob;
        public string Image;


        public Connection(Guid id, string firstname, DateTime dob, string Image)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.firstname = firstname;
            this.dob = dob;
            this.Image = Image;
        }
    }
}
```

Error Message

```
Error   1   'GoDating.Dates' does not contain a constructor that takes 6 arguments  C:\Users\###\SkyDrive\GODating\GODating\GoDating\Database_Operations\DateDAO.cs 52  39  GoDating
```

Comment: Include the error message as text, not as a screenshot of the error message.

Comment: Taking your posted code, I can type `Dates dates = new Dates(new Guid(), "", new DateTime(), "", "", new DateTime());` with no problems.

Comment: Could the "Image" type be causing you issues? Try using a variable name that is not a keyword (i.e. Picture).

Comment: Do you maybe have another `Dates` class defined elsewhere, and it's looking at that one instead of this one? Try using the fully-qualified name when calling it, see if that helps.

Comment: Your code is for `GoDating.Models.Dates`, but the error message is talking about `GoDating.Dates`.  As Joe Enos says, you need to fully-qualify your type to get the right one.

Comment: I renamed the Dates class to UserDates and now it's working. Don't know why it wasn't working ?

Comment: @user3922757 because you had two classes named `Dates` and it was resolving to the wrong one.

Comment: @juharr I don't have another class though. I renamed the class to UserDates and then renamed it back to Dates an now it's working http://i.imgur.com/sZdE0jG.png

Comment: @user3922757 Did you recently change the namespace for that class from `GoDating` to `GoDating.Models`?  If not, I have no idea why it was looking in the wrong namespace if there truly isn't another class called `Dates` there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
Dates dates = new Dates(
    rdr.GetGuid(0), 
    rdr.GetString(1), 
    rdr.GetDateTime(2), 
    rdr.GetString(3), 
    rdr.GetString(4), 
    rdr.GetDateTime(5));
```

with

```
GoDating.Models.Dates dates = new GoDating.Models.Dates(
    rdr.GetGuid(0), 
    rdr.GetString(1), 
    rdr.GetDateTime(2), 
    rdr.GetString(3), 
    rdr.GetString(4), 
    rdr.GetDateTime(5));
```

Right now it's resolving to `GoDating.Dates` which must not have a constructor with 6 parameters.

Or as you've already figured out, use unique names for your classes.

Comment: I renamed the class to UserDates and then renamed it back to Dates an now it's [working](http://i.imgur.com/sZdE0jG.png)  I'm going to use your method to ensure it doesn't happen again. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The use fully qualified name or complete assembly name like

GoDating.Models.Dates dates = new GoDating.Models.Dates(rdr.GetGuid(0), rdr.GetString(1), 
            rdr.GetDateTime(2), rdr.GetString(3), rdr.GetString(4), 
            rdr.GetDateTime(5));